# Merge array with underscore by keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays :

```
[{id:1,name:"name"},{id:2,name:"name2"} ,{id:3,name:"name3"}]

[{id:1,date:"123"},{id:2,date:"456"}]
```

Array 1 should be updated only if the id is equal :
So the array 1 will looks like

It should not create a new array . Only update the array 1 based on array 2

```
[{id:1,name:"name",date:"123"},{id:2,name:"name2",date:"456"} ,{id:3,name:"name3"}]
```

I managed to do that with for loop on `array2` and inside the for filter like the following :

```
._filter(array1,function(item){
 If(item.id=array2.id)
    Do smth and update the array1.date
})
```

How do I doing that in he best way ? Using underscore.js

Comment: Please invest some time in formatting your question correctly and proofreading your code to correct typos before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using native language like this:

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1,name:"name"},{id:2,name:"name2"} ,{id:3,name:"name3"}];
const arr2 = [{id:1,date:"123"},{id:2,date:"456"}];

arr1.forEach((ele) => {
   const match = arr2.find(item => ele.id === item.id) || {};   
   Object.assign(ele, match);
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Iterate over array1 and check if the id of each item exists in array2 by using the `some()` method.

```js
var arr1 = [{id:1,name:"name"},{id:2,name:"name2"} ,{id:3,name:"name3"}];
var arr2 = [{id:1,date:"123"},{id:2,date:"456"}];

var missing = [];

arr1.forEach( (item1, i) => {
  var isExist = arr2.some(item2 => item2.id === item1.id)
  
  if(!isExist) {
    missing.push(i);
  }
 
})

missing.forEach(item => {
 arr2.push(arr1[item]);
})

console.log(arr2);
```

reference for [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var a = [{id:1,name:"name"},{id:2,name:"name2"} ,{id:3,name:"name3"}] ;
var b = [{id:1,date:"123"},{id:2,date:"456"}] ;
var i = 0, j = 0 ;

while( i < a.length ) {
  j = 0 ;
  while( j < b.length) {
    if ( a[i].id === b[j].id )
      Object.assign( a[i] , b[j] );
    j++; 
  }
  i++;
}

console.log(a) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to iterate over the second array and use `findIndex` to get the matched element from first array. If the `id` matches then update the object in the first array

```js
let arr1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "name"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "name2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "name3"
}]
let arr2 = [{
  id: 1,
  date: "123"
}, {
  id: 2,
  date: "456"
}]

arr2.forEach(function(acc) {
  let findArry1Index = arr1.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.id === acc.id;
  });
  if (findArry1Index !== -1) {
    arr1[findArry1Index].date = acc.date;
  }
});

console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [{id:1,name:"name"},{id:2,name:"name2"} ,{id:3,name:"name3"}];

var b = [{id:1,date:"123"},{id:2,date:"456"}];

a = _.map(a, function(e) { return _.extend(e, _.findWhere(b, {id: e.id})); });
```

a results in:

```
0: {id: 1, name: "name", date: "123"}
1: {id: 2, name: "name2", date: "456"}
2: {id: 3, name: "name3"}
```

However, I guess this qualifies as "creating a new array"? Maybe it can serve as an inspiration though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

You can use underscore's [`indexBy`](https://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) function to index your second array by `id`, and then simply use `Object.assign(...)` to update your first array's elements with their corresponding match by performing a lookup in the indexed elements object.

```js
let arr1 = [{id:1, name:"name"}, {id:2, name:"name2"}, {id:3, name:"name3"}]
let arr2 = [{id:1, date:"123"}, {id:2, date:"456"}]

const arr2Groups = _.indexBy(arr2, e => e.id);

arr1.forEach(e => Object.assign(e, arr2Groups[e.id] || {}));
console.log(arr1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```